# ImageView image explorer

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, nullpointerexception, imageview

**Hello,**

When I try to insert an imageview with the image explorer, I get an error when launching it.

**fragment_accueil.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.accueil.AccueilFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_login"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bienvenue !"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_appartment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ajouter un appartement"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_delete_appartment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enlever un appartement"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_find_agent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ajouter un agent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_delete_agent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enlever un agent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView avatar;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications, R.id.navigation_incidents)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


        avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar_login);
        avatar.setClickable(true);
        avatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }
    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            avatar.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

}
```

Error code

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.gestloc, PID: 10359
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gestloc/com.example.gestloc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setClickable(boolean)' on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setClickable(boolean)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.gestloc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10359 SIG: 9

**Thanks you,**